# Como anular o destruir una variable en c#

Tags: c#

Como puedo establecer una variable y un textbox en c# a null.

Probe variable = null; y no funciona, con el textbox hice lo siguiente textbox.Text = string.Empty;

Tambien intente textbox.Text = null; y nada de eso funciona.

---

> Esto esta en el formulario

```
Miembro.nombre = txtNombre.Text;            
        Miembro.email = txtEmail.Text;
        Miembro.dir_postal = txtDirPostal.Text;
        Miembro.pueblo_postal = txtPuebloPostal.Text;
        Miembro.codigo_postal = txtCodPosP.Text;
        Miembro.dir_fisica = txtDirFisica.Text;
        Miembro.pueblo_fisica = txtPuebloFisica.Text;
        Miembro.codigo_fisica = txtCodPosF.Text;
        Miembro.celular = Cel;
        Miembro.telefono = TelCasa;
        Miembro.idsociedad = id_sociedad;
        Miembro.invitado_por = id_invitadopor;
        Miembro.fecha_comienzo = fec_comienzo.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Miembro.fecha_membresia = fec_membresia.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Miembro.fecha_nac = fecNacimiento.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Miembro.sexo = cboGenero.Text;
        Miembro.estadocivil = cboEstCivil.Text;
        Miembro.conyuge = txtNombreConyuge.Text;

Miembro.Actualizar(idmiembro);
```

> En una clase aparte esta lo siguiente

```
public string Actualizar(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            string cadena = "update miembros set nombre='" + nombre;
            if (email == "") { } { cadena += "', email='" + email; }
            if (dir_postal != "") { cadena += "', dir_postal='" + dir_postal; }
            if (pueblo_postal != "") { cadena += "', pueblo_postal='" + pueblo_postal; }
            if (codigo_postal != "") { cadena += "', codigo_postal='" + codigo_postal; }
            if (dir_fisica != "") { cadena += "', dir_fisica='" + dir_fisica; }
            if (pueblo_fisica != "") { cadena += "', pueblo_fisica='" + pueblo_fisica; }
            if (codigo_fisica != "") { cadena += "', codigo_fisica='" + codigo_fisica; }
            if (celular != "") { cadena += "', celular='" + celular; }
            if (telefono != "") { cadena += "', telefono='" + telefono; }
            if (idsociedad != 0) { cadena += "', idsociedad='" + idsociedad; }
            if (invitado_por != 0) { cadena += "', invitado_por='" + invitado_por; }
            if (fecha_comienzo != "") { cadena += "', fecha_comienzo='" + fecha_comienzo; }
            if (fecha_membresia != "") { cadena += "', fecha_membresia='" + fecha_membresia; }
            if (fecha_nac != "") { cadena += "', fecha_nac='" + fecha_nac; }
            if (sexo != "Selecciona...") { cadena += "', sexo='" + sexo; }
            if (estadocivil != "Selecciona...") { cadena += "', estadocivil='" + estadocivil; }
            if (conyuge != "") { cadena += "', conyuge='" + conyuge; }
            if (foto == "") { cadena += "', foto='" + foto; }
            cadena += "', miembro='" + miembro;
            if (bautizado != "Selecciona...") { cadena += "', bautizado='" + bautizado; }
            if (nombre_emergencia != "") { cadena += "', nombre_emergencia='" + nombre_emergencia; }
            if (telefono_emergencia != "") { cadena += "', telefono_emergencia='" + telefono_emergencia; }
            cadena += "', updated_at='" + updated_at + "', idupdated_by='" + idupdated_by + "' where id='" + id + "'";

            MessageBox.Show(cadena);
            SQLiteCommand comando = new SQLiteCommand(cadena, conexion);
            comando.CommandTimeout = 0;

            conexion.Open();
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(comando.ExecuteNonQuery()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Se modificaron los datos de la persona", "Miembro Actualizado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo guardar la imformaci�n", "Error...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            conexion.Close();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Eso que haces, funciona en todos los casos.. que es lo que queres lograr que decis que eso no funciona?

Comment: null y una cadena vacio, son datos validos en todos los casos... si mandas un nulo a la base de datos, el campo va a quedar nulo. Si haces un insert y no mandas el campo, el campo va a quedar nulo...

Comment: @AngelRodriguez, en tu base de datos debes poner que el campo sea de tipo null, para que te permita guardar valores vacios o nulos, y otra cosa que veo que no has dicho cual es tu base de datos?

Comment: Asi esta, los campos permiten valores null, estoy usando sqlite

Comment: Angel, tratamos de ayudarte, pero tenes que ser claro planteando el problema y siguiendo los lineamientos de como hacer una buena pregunta (que te pase los links) para que puedas obtener una buena respuesta. Saque el tag sqlite, porque tu pregunta original no tenia nada que ver con eso. usa el boton [edit] y podes modificar tu pregunta tanto como haga falta. Deja todo tu problema claro. Tu codigo tiene los ifs necesarios, cual seria el problema entonces? que campo llega que no tiene que llegar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi me sirve mucho

```
if (txtDescrip.Text.Length == 0){
```

// Ejecuto la acción.
}else{
//Muestro un mensaje que me indique que se debe de escribir algo en el campo u no puede estar vacio.
}

Comment: Daniel te la comiste brother, no se me habia ocurrido eso y funciono perfectamente, gracias, excelente!!

Comment: @AngelRodriguez, si la respuesta dada te fue util no olvides marcarla como aceptada

Comment: Perfecto @Japv, hecho, poco a poco iré aprendiendo, como funciona este foro, gracias

Comment: Yo todavia no entiendo tu pregunta.. la verdad que adivino la respuesta... esto que esta asi, se puede hacer tambien con la clase string (IsNullOrEmpty)...

Comment: @DanielOchoa Gracias por tu contribución pero es demasiado importante revisar [answer], saludos.